# Why tensorflow precision and recall are so different from the same sklearn metrics

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, metrics

Hello I have a lot of trouble understanding why I get such a good score on the validation set with tensorflow metrics when I have a very bad score on this same validation set with sklearn metrics.

My CNN model has this shape :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(100,8)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
[tf.keras.metrics.Recall,tf.keras.metrics.Precision])

model.fit(X_train2,
       Y_train2,
       epochs=11,
       batch_size=25,
       verbose=1,
       validation_data=(X_val2,Y_val2),
       class_weight=class_weight)
```

I get the following results:

```
 Epoch 1/11
 11088/11088 [==============================] - 80s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6293 - recall_m: 0.6242 - 
 precision_m: 0.6242 - f1_m: 0.6242 - val_loss: 0.6388 - val_recall_m: 0.5813 - val_precision_m: 
 0.5813 - val_f1_m: 0.5813


 Epoch 2/11
 11088/11088 [==============================] - 73s 7ms/step - loss: 0.5729 - recall_m: 0.6825 - 
 precision_m: 0.6825 - f1_m: 0.6825 - val_loss: 0.5060 - val_recall_m: 0.8066 - val_precision_m: 
 0.8066 - val_f1_m: 0.8066
```

While using this trained model to predict my labels then using sklearn metrics (recall_score and precision_score) I get very different results :

```
    pred=model.predict(X_val2)
    pred=pred.argmax(axis=1)
    Y_true=Y_val2.argmax(axis=1)

    print("precision_score",precision_score(Y_true,pred))
    print("recall_score",recall_score(Y_true,pred))
```

```
precision_score 0.23023467760309865
recall_score 0.49839704069050556
```

Comment: `Y_true=Y_val2.argmax(axis=1)` what are you doing here? You already have the Y_val2, can you use that directly?

Comment: I one hot encode Y_val2 so i need to create a Y_true vector

Comment: oh, I see... Can you run it for a longer epoch, then maybe do a manual calculation of TP, TN, FP, FN, from which you can get precision, recall, etc manually. I think those values might give you a bit of insight.

Comment: hi i find the solution of my problem thanks, it was because tensorflow invers my classe 1 and class 2 because i one hot encode a binary class

Comment: @RaphaëlGervillié how to fix this do you have the solution